# Js как сделать чтобы функция возвращала значение?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Пишу так:

```
    $scope.localSearch = function () {
        var matches = 123;
        return matches;
    };

    console.log($scope.localSearch);
```

В консоли:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как вернуть саму переменную а не функцию?

Comment: не сильно знаком с javascript, но, вероятно: console.log($scope.localSearch());

Comment: например вызвать ее `console.log($scope.localSearch());`

Comment: @Grundy, жесть)) в уроках же учили что если функция возвращает значения, скобки не нужны) спасибо

Comment: @SdafsFasafs, покажи это место _что если функция возвращает значения, скобки не нужны_

Comment: `$scope.localSearch` - содержит ссылку на функцию с телом   
` var matches = 123;return matches;`, что - бы вернуть значение нужно функцию запустить `()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Или так

```
$scope.localSearch = function () {
    var matches = 123;
    return matches;
}();

console.log($scope.localSearch);
```

Comment: Локаничние! На сколько повлияет на поведение функции, добавление `()` в конце? Вроде как выполнить сразу, но на как оно дальше вести себя будет? Теперь можно везде вызвать без скобок `$scope.localSearch`. Какая обратна сторона медали?

Comment: @borodatych, вообще не понял вопроса :) мы просто сразу выполнили функцию и результат записали в переменную. В принципе все.

Comment: Может так: *минус подхода в том, что за счет того, что выполнение происходит сразу, то необходимые данные должны быть объявлены до объявления функция. Что означает, что теряется биндинг* ??

Comment: @borodatych, это если функция использует какие-то левые данные, и непонятно что за binding

Comment: Добавил к себе под `UPD` про что говорю, прокомментируйте пожалуйста, вдруг заблуждаюсь.

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```
$scope.localSearch = function () {
    var matches = 123;
    return matches;
};
$scope.myVar = $scope.localSearch();

console.log( $scope.myVar );
```

**UPD**
Использование через `function(){}()`:

```
$scope.test = 0;
$scope.localSearch = function () {
    return $scope.test;
}();
$interval(function(){
    console.log("EVERY 1 SEC: " + $scope.localSearch);
},1000);
 $interval(function(){
    $scope.test++;
    console.log("EVERY 3 SEC: " + $scope.test);
    console.log("EVERY 3 SEC: " + $scope.localSearch);
 },3000);
```

> Если `localSearch` должен зависеть от `$scope.test` и `$scope.test` примитив, то лучше отказаться от данного способа!

Comment: да, с примитивным значением - да, но если б `$scope.test` - был бы объектом, и менялись его поля - то никакой разницы бы не было

Comment: Действительно, спасибо. Поправил. Но что то меня все равно гложит....